# Is that possible to subscribe more than one time for one product google play store Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am making app with using unity engine. In my app, i have a product (type:SUBSCRIBE) that user can paid monthly for the product.

But i need the user can subscribe for more than one for a same product. Is that possible to do that ?

I am not asking for how to code it in unity. But i am asking is that possible for double or triple subscription for a same product with using a same google play account ?

Example :
User account A purchase ITEM 01 (TYPE : SUBSCRIPTION) with monthly paid $30 after that user account A purchase a same item again ITEM O1 (TYPE : SUBSCRIPTION). So now user account A paid double $30 = $60 a month.

Is that possible ?

Thank You

Comment: i highly doubt ,there are consumables and subscriptions . i guess google only allows for consumables to be purchased more than once.

Comment: @AllanBanis are you sure about this ?

Comment: yes one google account can buy only one subscription . but it is possible to buy multiple subscriptions to a app via different google accounts on the same device. but the app will load only the current users subscription . if the user has the subscription already then google play will throw a message saying 'you are already subscribed'. but it is good practice to not give a subscribed user the option to subscribe again.

Comment: Can an app offer multiple subscriptions with different product ids and can a user purchase more than one from among these subscriptions? These multiple multiple subscriptions can be thought to be for different types of content in the same app. Maybe different subscriptions from different sources or of different categories.

Can the user have more than one active running subscriptions at the same time?